# Where you think he lives. / How old you think she is

Tags: grammar

I want to know the following process is possible.

.

A-1. Do you think ~ + Where does he live?

A-2. => Where do you think he lives?

A-3. => where you think he lives. [Indirect question order.]

A-4. => This is where you think he lives.

Is it right?

.

B-1. Do you think ~ + How old is she?

B-2 => How old do you think she is?

C-3 => how old you think she is [Indirect questions order.]

C-4 => thirty-five is how old you think she is.

Is it right?

Comment: Both are _possible_, but not very idiomatic. A native speaker would be more likely to say something like "You think she's about 35" or "You would estimate her age as 35".

Comment: Hi Thank you for your confirmation! But I am wondering what indirect question refers to. I mean, for example, <how old you think she is> —> it may refer to a fact such as something numerical?

Comment: <where you think she lives> —> it may refer to a fact such as a place?

Comment: Lastly, I saw an American book name so called “You are not who you think you are”. In this sentence, <who you think you are> —> it only refers to a fact, but I have to be careful to use indirect question-who. Because as you can see the following sentence...... Direct Q: Who you see —> Indirect Q: who I see —> and then I can put this indirect Q in another sentence like this. ==> Who I see is very handsome. (X)... Not any native speakers say like this.

Comment: Instead, I can put the Indirect Q into another sentence while considering the semantics like this. ==> Who I see is irrelevant to a crime. / You can guess who Is see at the party. / It doesn’t matter to my boss who I see.

Comment: An indirect question is a question which forms part of a longer sentence, like "Is that where you think he lives?" or "I wonder how old you think she is". Your C4 is not idiomatic, as I said.

Comment: "You are not who you think you are" does _not_ contain an indirect question. "Who you think you are" and "Who I see" are not questions - that would be "Who do you think you are?" and "Who do I (or "can I") see?"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117201/discussion-between-tae-bbong-e-and-kate-bunting).